# a SQL multi-match join from Stanford open course

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

You've started a new movie-rating website, and you've been collecting data on reviewers' ratings of various movies. There's not much data yet, but you can still try out some interesting queries. Here's the schema:

Movie ( mID, title, year, director ) 
English: There is a movie with ID number mID, a title, a release year, and a director.

Reviewer ( rID, name ) 
English: The reviewer with ID number rID has a certain name.

Rating ( rID, mID, stars, ratingDate ) 
English: The reviewer rID gave the movie mID a number of stars rating (1-5) on a certain ratingDate.

Question:
For each director, return the director's name together with the title(s) of the movie(s) they directed that received the highest rating among all of their movies, and the value of that rating. Ignore movies whose director is NULL.

Note: Your queries are executed using SQLite, so you must conform to the SQL constructs supported by SQLite.

My understanding:
Each director may have multiple movies, each movie is rated by different reviewers. Highest rating here indeed is the highest average rating. I think this SQL should carry multiple subqueries or joins and the system accepted it after my 5 tries and it costs more than 10 mins. If this is an interview question from Google or Facebook, I would have failed. Anyone can give a elegant and concise solution?

I indeed googled the solution online and I found quite many wrong solutions, although they can pass the system small data check. For example, the following SQL is indeed incorrect.

```
select title, max(stars) as max_star, director
from Movie, Rating
where Movie.mID = Rating.mID and director is not NULL
group by director;
```

My solution is as follows, if anyone can provide a more elegant but logic correct solution, please let me know.Thanks

```
select Q2.director, title, maxStar from Movie m join
(select director, mID, max(stars) as maxStar from
(select director, mID, stars
from Movie m join Rating r using(mID)
where director NOT NULL
group by mID ) Q1
group by director ) Q2
on m.mID = Q2.mID;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below:

```
Select Movie.title,
       MAX(A.rate),
       Movie.director (Select  rID, mID, AVG(stars) as rate, ratingDate 
                       From Rating Group By mID
                       ) A 
       Inner Join Movie on A.mID=Movie.mID  
where Movie.director is not NULL
group by Movie.director;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.director, m.title, r.stars 
FROM movie m
JOIN rating r USING(mid)
JOIN (SELECT director, max(stars) AS rate
       FROM movie
       JOIN rating USING(mid)
       WHERE director IS NOT NULL
       GROUP BY director) q
ON q.director=m.director AND r.stars=q.rate
ORDER BY m.director
```

I am not an expert, but this query worked for me. And I think it is easy to understand. First I query directors with their highest ratings and then I write my main query using my inner query as a filter.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.director, t.title, t.stars, t.ratingdate, t.rankmy 
from (
select m.director, m.title, rt.stars, rt.ratingdate, row_number() over( partition by m.director order by rt.stars desc) rankmy
from movie m inner join rating rt on m.mid = rt.mid 
where m.director is not null ) T
where t.rankmy = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct q.director,title,stars
from (select director,max(stars) as b
    from Movie natural join rating
    where director is not null
    group by director) q,
    (select * from Movie natural join rating ) w
where q.director=w.director and q.b=w.stars
```